# safe way to install AMD Catalyst Control Centre?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

Relatively noob here. I'm having a blast with Ubuntu, successfully playing all kinds of steam games, no complaints until Firewatch came out.
It was recommended to me to install AMD Catalyst Control Centre.
I tried doing this several ways
(followed these guidelines: 
[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/435796#435796)

and also once: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka5gBMlo-zo)

Unfortunately, after I install the fglrx driver, and reboot, I only get a black screen, and cannot revert my installation (as I don't see anything), and I already reinstalled 14.04 twice.
As you can see, I'm obviously not an expert, but I would like to be able to try out something, without messing up everything, preventing a necessary reinstall of everything.
Is there a safe 'sandbox' mode to try things, or how can i reboot to a non-graphical interface (command line only) and revert wrong installations?
Alternatively, any tips on how to safely install AMD Catalyst Control Centre?

Thanks so much!!

Specs:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory 11.7 GiB
Intel Core 17-2670QM CPU@ 2.20GHz x8
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6850M
OS: 64-bit
DisK 120 GB

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the command line by pressing CTRL+ALT+F6. (or anything between F1 & F8) they are all TTY's, the desktop usually runs on TTY7 (CTRL+ALT+F7).
do `sudo apt-get remove` for anything you installed before reboot. and cross your fingers.